# Cannot import AWSCore into my own iOS Framework

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-web-services, ios-frameworks

I am developing an own Framework which uses AWSCore and AWSS3 from AWS. I have inserted the Core and S3 Frameworks under the General -> 'Linked frameworks and Libraries' section of the Own Framework target as I did with my Single Target App and where its simply works. But the `import AWSS3` statement gives the error `No such module 'AWSS3`

What is the right way to import the AWS Frameworks into my own Frameworks?

Comment: Are you trying to build a Swift framework? Can you consume via cocoa pods with 'use_frameworks!' option?

Comment: Can you add the frameworks under "Build Settings" -> "Embed Frameworks" section as well? Let us know if this works for you.

Comment: @Karthikeyan, Are you sure about "Build Settings" -> "Embed Frameworks"  under a Framework target?

Comment: could you provide a simple setup where we can reproduce this issue?